# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Result<Any>' with an argument list of type '(int,int)' on Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: swift, generics, tuples, xcode7.3

Trying this on a playground on Xcode 7.3.1 gives me compilation error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Result<Any>' with an argument list of type '(int,int)'
```

On Xcode 7.3 it runs fine though. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
public enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(ErrorType)
    public init(_ value: T) {
        self = .Success(value)
    }
    public init(_ error: ErrorType) {
        self = .Failure(error)
    }
}
func handleResult(result: Result<Any>) {
    switch result {
    case .Success(let value):
        print(value)
    case .Failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
let b = Result<Any>((1,2))    //This doesn't work on Xcode 7.3.1
handleResult(b)
```

Any ideas? Did the Xcode 7.3.1 compiler become stricter?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what changed for the compiler but imho you should drop the explicit `Result<Any>` anyway and stay generic:

```
func handleResult<T>(result: Result<T>) {
    switch result {
    case .Success(let value):
        print(value)
    case .Failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}

let b = Result((1,2))
handleResult(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Functions - Omitting External Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) may help you in understanding I suppose.

```
 import UIKit
 public enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(ErrorType)
    public init(value: T) {
        self = .Success(value)
    }
    public init(error: ErrorType) {
        self = .Failure(error)
    }
}

func handleResult(result: Result<Any>) {
            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                print(value)
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

let b = Result<Any>(value: (1,2))    //This works only on Xcode 7.3.1
        handleResult(b)
```